# Set of real numbers such that no sum of its elements is an element and all partial sums are unique.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to construct a set $A$ with $n$ real numbers $a_i,$ with $i\in I = \{1,2,\dots, n\}$ with two properties. Firstly $$\forall I'\subseteq I:\sum_{i \in I'} a_i \notin A$$ and secondly $\forall I', I''\subset I$ where $I'\neq I''$ we have$$ \sum_{i \in I'} a_i \neq \sum_{i \in I''} a_i.$$

Do sets like this have a name? If it is not possible, could you elaborate as to what exactly makes this fail?

Comment: Noting that $|I''|=1$ is possible, the first restriction seems redundant.

Comment: How about $\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},\sqrt{11},\dots,\sqrt{p_n}\}$? I think the partial sums of these numbers are all unique and they don't reduce further, and you can *probably* prove that with some group theory shenanigans.

Comment: For $~b \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ the infinite set $ ~S = \{ ~1,b,b^2,b^3,\cdots ~\}, ~$ or any subset of $~S~$ works.  The elements in the set $~S~$ are the only positive integers whose base $~b~$ expression has exactly $~1~$ digit.

Comment: If $n\geq 1,\ $ then $\ a_1\in A.\ $ Also, $\ \{1\}\subset I,\ $ and since $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i\in\{1\}} a_i = a_1 \in A,\ $ and we see that the first property fails if $\ n\geq 1.$ So you need to amend this...

Answer (score 0):

Logs of the first $n$ prime numbers satisfy your requirements.